# How to open a link to a Java file within Eclipse with the default editor instead the browser?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, hyperlink

In my Eclipse Java project I have a website that contains links like that to Java files from the same project:

```
<a href="../src/Test.java" target="_blank">asdjakl</a>
```

When clicking on the link, the Java file is correctly opened in a new browser window. However, I want to open it with the default editor in Eclipse. How can I do that?